# Getting an array of objects using FirebaseFirestoreSwift

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore

I have a struct that looks like this:

```
struct Joint: Identifiable, Codable {
    @DocumentID var id : String? = UUID().uuidString
    var serviceType : Int
    var businessName : String
    var keywords: [String]
    var menu : [DishItems]
    
    enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case businessName
        case serviceType = "jointType"
        case keywords
        case menu
    }
}

struct DishItems: Codable {
    var listOrder : Int
    var menuItemName : String
    var menuItemDescription : String
    var menuItemPrice : Double
}
```

The DishItems is a custom object and I am using FirebaseFireStoreSwift JSON decoder to retrieve the documents.

```
let db = Firestore.firestore().collection("Joints")
        db.getDocuments { (querySnapshot, error) in
            guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else {
                print("No restaurants")
                return
            }
            
            let jointsArray : [Joint] = documents.compactMap { 
                return try? $0.data(as: Joint.self)
            }
            
            completion(jointsArray)
        }
```

I am able to query all of the documents if I exclude "menu" from the parent struct but as soon as I include it, then nothing is queried. How do I go about obtaining the array of objects inside the JSON?

[image]

Comment: cann you show your structure of firebase ?

Comment: @jawadAli I added an image of the structure.

Comment: any error you are getting ?

Comment: No error. Not even an empty array.

Comment: what you get in array ?

Comment: I followed this tutorial https://youtu.be/3-yQeAf3bLE